# Arrays with NULL keys

Tags: php, arrays, null

PHP trivia here.

If we declare an array like this:

```
<?php $arr = [ 'foo' => 'bar', NULL => 'hello' ]; ?>
```

We can access it like this

```
print $arr[NULL];
```

This will print `hello`. Why is this useful, relevant or necessary? Is it a PHP bug or a feature?

My only idea was that you could declare array with the NULL key being equal to an error message to explain to anyone who uses a NULL key that their key is null:

```
$arr[NULL] = 'Warning you have used a null key, did you mean to?';
```

Has anyone found this useful? Seems to be something to cause more harm than good.

Comment: "more harm than good" can be said about a lot of things in PHP...

Comment: @DCoder sometimes that appears to be php motto

Comment: +1 I am happy this works, I think having a null key can be very usefull

Comment: @DCoder "more harm than good" can be said about PHP. ← fixed that for you.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Quote from [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

> Null will be cast to the empty string, i.e. the key `null` will
> actually be stored under `""`.

Additional details about how keys are cast are as follows:

> The key can either be an int or a string. The value can be of any
> type.
>
> Additionally the following key casts will occur:
>
> - Strings containing valid decimal ints, unless the number is preceded by a `+` sign, will be cast to the int type. E.g. the key `"8"` will
>   actually be stored under `8`. On the other hand `"08"` will not be
>   cast, as it isn't a valid decimal integer.
> - Floats are also cast to ints, which means that the fractional part will be truncated. E.g. the key `8.7` will actually be stored under
>   `8`.
> - Bools are cast to ints, too, i.e. the key `true` will actually be stored under `1` and the key `false` under `0`.
> - Null will be cast to the empty string, i.e. the key `null` will actually be stored under `""`.
> - Arrays and objects can not be used as keys. Doing so will result in a warning: `Illegal offset type`.

As for this being useful or necessary, this is debatable. You are asked to use integer or string keys and you have been warned about implicit key casting.

Comment: _the key null will actually be stored under `""`_ overwriting previous value if there is one. Such item can be accessed by `$arr[""]`; `$arr[NULL]` will return the item stored at `""`.

Answer (score 12):

I have found the possibility to have Null keys useful, when accessing db, using a class, which can use one of the column values as the key to the returned array. Some column values could be null.

Comment: I have also found this useful for the same reason.

Comment: If another column value is an empty string `""`, you're in trouble.

Answer (score 5):

Given a form API populated by an associative php array, I have found it useful to use a null-keyed value to indicate the NULL value in a database. E.g.:

```
$this->addElement('select', 'foreignkey_id', array(
  'label'=>'Add a Poll',
  'multiOptions' => array(
      null => 'No value selected',
      '0' => 'Element with ID0 selected'
  )
));
```

In this case, null maps to a NULL (default) value in the database column foreignkey_id, and 0 to a row with key 0.

Outside this particular usecase however, I tend to think DCoder's comment is authoritative here...