# check value if null return 0 otherwise return the value

Tags: php

What is the shortest way to set if status is null return '0' else return the value.

```
$value['status'] = null;

$STATUSES = array(
    0 => 'Pending',
    1 => 'Accepted',
    2 => 'Suspended',
    3 => 'Rejected',
    4 => 'Waiting list',
    5 => 'Terminated',
    9 => 'Application in Progress'
);

$status = $STATUSES[$value['status']];

echo $status;
```

I can use empty() function to check if value is 'null' but I wanted to know if there is smarter way.

I am looking for a native function like this.

```
$status = $STATUSES[ valueToZiro( $value['status'] )];

function valueToZiro($val){
    return empty($val)?0:$val;
}
```

Comment: you should try searching on google before posting in SO.

Comment: What's the reason of the `define()`? It doesn't work and triggers a warning.

Comment: `isset` also check the value for whether it is null or not

Comment: Thank you all for your time and effort as I said I don't want to use any condition. we just had some fun here;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are sure for getting an integer for your `$value['status']` you can cast it to integer, it would be shorter:

```
// in case of null, casting will return 0
$status = $STATUSES[(int)$value['status']];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (array_key_exists($value['status'],$STATUSES) {
        return $STATUSES[$value['status']];
}
return 0;
```

Comment: `in_array` searches for array values, you need to use `array_key_exists` function in this case.

Answer (score 1):

```
return is_null($status)?0:$status;
```

Using empty will also return true on empty string `$var = ""` , on empty arrays `$var = array()` and on `0`. Using `is_null` is the safest way to check for a `null` value.

EDIT: Although this answer above answers your primary question, your question does not fit your code... To fix your code, I'd do:

```
$value['status'] = null;

$STATUSES = array(
    0 => 'Pending',
    1 => 'Accepted',
    2 => 'Suspended',
    3 => 'Rejected',
    4 => 'Waiting list',
    5 => 'Terminated',
    9 => 'Application in Progress'
);
define('STATUSES', $STATUSES);
if(isset($STATUSES[$value['status']])){
    echo $STATUSES[$value['status']];
}else{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: isn't it short function of if condition?

Comment: yes, php's ternary operator. http://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators

Comment: @Fury Correct it's called the ternary operator.

Comment: An IDE suggests to use `$status === null`, because `is_null` may become a deprecated function in new PHP versions

Comment: @Fury `?:` is an [operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php), `if` is a [control structure](http://php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php). An operator connects expressions into a bigger expression. A control structure decides what instruction runs next. They belong to totally different categories, there is no *"`?:` is the short of `if`"*.

Comment: @zazu good point, it is also faster to execute if micro-optimization is your thing

Answer (score 1):

PHP automatically converts a 'null' index to an empty string
So, adding an empty string ass key which has a value of `'0'`, fixes your problem without the need to check whether `$value['status']` is null.

```
$STATUSES = array(
  '' => '0',
  1  => 'Accepted',
  // etc
);
```

Whether this is a desirable method depends on your situation, I suppose...

See '[Arrays with NULL keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18247412/arrays-with-null-keys)' for more information on 'null keys'