# How remove key from array?

Tags: php, arrays, key

I have these arrays.

```
'tickets' => 
array (size=2)
  1 => 
    array (size=19)
      'ticket_id' => 1
      'ticket_event_id' => 158
      /* some good values */
  4 => 
    array (size=19)
      'ticket_id' => 4
      'ticket_event_id' => 158
```

And I would like to unset values 'ticket_id', 'ticket_event_id' and array key.
I used this code

```
foreach ($event['tickets'] as $ticketId => $ticket) {
            $ticket['ticket_id'] = null;
            $ticket['ticket_event_id'] = null;
            $event['tickets'][$ticketId] = array_replace($event['tickets'][$ticketId],$ticket);
        }
```

But I have no idea, where and how I can put some code to unset array key.

I would like to recive array in this form

```
null => 
    array (size=19)
      'ticket_id' => null
      'ticket_event_id' => null
      /* some good values */
null => 
    array (size=19)
      'ticket_id' => null
      'ticket_event_id' => null
```

Comment: You can't (array keys must be unique), but why would you want to anyway?

Comment: Why are you doing that ?...

Comment: I want to unset this values, populate this array to form and then assign not empty information about tickets to new event.
Now I have problem, because duplicated event get ticket keys from "parent" and "parent" lost information about tickets.

Comment: Perhaps this page can give you some information about Arrays with NULL keys: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18247412/arrays-with-null-keys

Comment: There's always the [unset function](http://php.net/unset)

Comment: Can't it be a number instead? Like `0` and `1`. I'm assuming this is for further placement of the key. Maybe you could elaborate on what you need...

Comment: I want to duplikate my event. Each event has array with tickets like $event[$ticketId][$ticketData]. When I click duplicate event button, my duplicated event has tickets from event witch I used to duplikate. I need this $ticketData to populate to new form, but without $ticketId