# Target array element that has a blank key/name

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array being generated by data which I have no control over and it returns the below array. Is there a way to target specifically the element that has a blank key/name?

I've tried `$array['']`, `$array[' ']` and `$array[0]` but none of them seem to work. Is there another way without looping through the array, the empty key/name can be anywhere in the array, it's not necessarily the last array element?

`var_dump(array_keys($array));` gives me `[0]=> string(2) " "` for the element in question, I've tried targeting the element with a single and double space as the key/name but still gives an undefined index error.

I've also run `serialize()`on the keys from the array and the element with the blank key/name is returning `s:2:" ";`.

**Array**

```
Array
(
    [desc] => Information etc.
    [ref] => 2
    [ ] => 123
)
```

Comment: maybe `&nbsp;` hahaha :p, if you're checking it thru a browser, might want to check `view source` to find out

Comment: @Ghost, if only it was that simple, tried it with no luck. In the source it's just empty like it's displayed in the browser.

Comment: `var_dump()` to see.

Comment: Have you tried $array[NULL]

Comment: try `var_dump(array_keys($array));`

Comment: @AbraCadaver, shows up as ` [" "]=> string(1) "1"` with `var_dump()` but I can't target it with `$array[" "]`, gives an `Undefined index` error.

Comment: @Andrew, `array_keys` gives me `[0]=>  string(2) " "`, I've tried targeting the element with a single and double space as the key/name but still gives an `undefined index` error.

Comment: what about this? This works, I've tried. 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/18247435/2190689

Comment: @ssi-anik, no luck with that either.

Comment: what about `var_dump(ord(array_search(123, $array) ) );` ??

Answer (score -1):

It i probably not '' but something that shows up as '' (null maybe ?). Try `var_dump(array_keys($array))` to get actual key values and types. this should show you the proper key to use

Comment: is it a coincidence that your syntax is the same as my comment ...lol ?!

Comment: `array_keys` gives me `[0]=> string(2) " "`, I've tried targeting the element with a single and double space as the key/name but still gives an `undefined index` error.

Comment: call serialize() on it and paste the result somewhere, I'll debug it for you

Comment: When I grab it from the post it has only a single character ' 'although it clearly states it should have two. So probably its some utf character that got filtered out. To catch it first assign that particular key to some variable, and try using ord() on each character in that string. Tell me if you find something