# Is it fine to keep an empty string as array key?

Tags: php, arrays, key

I want to know is it fine if we keep an empty string as array key, like this

```
$test = array (
  '' => 'Select',
  1 => 'Internal',
  2 => 'External'
);
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18247412/arrays-with-null-keys

Comment: In this situation it looks totally fine. Usually use it when populating a `<select>` menu.

Comment: I would avoid this as it will lead to confusing errors if at any point in the future you try to json_encode or cast the array to an object.

Answer (score 8):

Array keys should either be an integer or a string.
 
Dealing with empty string as array key is far from ideal practice.
Also *Null* will be cast to the empty string, i.e. the key null will actually be stored under "".
But such approach makes your array as ambiguous and erratic.
Consider the following examples:

```
$test = array (
  '' => 'Select',
  1 => 'Internal',
  2 => 'External',
  '' => 'select'
);

var_dump(array_key_exists('', $test));   // output 'bool(true)', not so bad - but only at first glance
```

the next case comes to ambiguity:

```
var_dump($test[""]);   // output "select"
```

and the last example comes to error(notice):

```
var_dump((object) $test);
// output: object(stdClass)#1 (3) { E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Illegal member variable name -- at line 12 [""]=> string(6) "select" [1]=> string(8) "Internal" [2]=> string(8) "External" }
```

Comment: You made my concepts clear.

Comment: How is your second example ambiguous? You first set '' to 'Select', and then overwrite it with 'select'. This is well defined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

This will work fine but not good approach. For example, if you need to check null key of array then this empty string will return true. This approach will make syntax errors in other strictly typed languages like java and C.
So its better to avoid such coding :)